# Read excel file uploaded to s3 via node lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to parse through an excel file that is uploaded to s3 using [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) in a node lambda function that triggers on any s3 put. Here is my code which currently doesn't work. Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });
const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  // Get the object from the event and show its content type
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(
    event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " ")
  );
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key
  };

  try {
    const doc = await s3.getObject(params);
    const parsedDoc = await readXlsxFile(doc);
    console.log(parsedDoc)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.`;
    console.log(message);
    throw new Error(message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used lambda functions, but I have done something very similar in firebase functions. I used [convert-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json).

I first downloaded the excel file from firebase storage to the firebase functions machine. Then use this npm module to extract the information.

I don't have time to format the code, but I can leave it here for reference:

```js
// Runs when excel file is uploaded to storage
exports.uploadOrder = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (file) => {
  const fileBucket = file.bucket;
  const filePath = file.name || "null";
  const filePathList = filePath?.split("/") || ["null"];
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

  if (filePathList[0] !== "excel_orders") {
    return;
  }

  const uid = filePathList[1];
  console.log("User ID: " + uid);

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

  console.log(tempFilePath);

  await bucket.file(filePath).download({ destination: tempFilePath });

  const result = excelToJson({
    sourceFile: tempFilePath,
  });

  var ordersObj: any[] = result.Sheet1;
  ordersObj.shift();

  console.log(ordersObj);

  var orders: any[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < ordersObj.length; i++) {
    const order: Order = {
      package_description: ordersObj[i].A,
      package_type: ordersObj[i].B,
      country: ordersObj[i].C,
      address: ordersObj[i].D,
      curstomer_name: ordersObj[i].E,
      customer_phone: ordersObj[i].F,
      collection_ammount: ordersObj[i].G,
      order_date: ordersObj[i].H,
      delivery_date: ordersObj[i].I,
      delivery_time: ordersObj[i].J,
      status: "pending",
      assignedTo: "",
      merchantID: uid,
    };

    orders.push(order);
  }

});
```